# Python generating list with unique lexical elements

Tags: python, arrays, list, list-comprehension

Suppose I want to make an empty 3x4 2d array like such.

```
x = [[0.0]*3]*4
```

However, using the above code,

```
print x[0] is x[1]     # Output = True
```

Meaning,

```
x[1][1] = 5.0
print x      # Output = [[0.0, 5.0, 0.0], 
             #           [0.0, 5.0, 0.0], 
             #           [0.0, 5.0, 0.0], 
             #           [0.0, 5.0, 0.0]]
```

To bypass creating this list with 4 identical references to the same list, I've been doing things like:

```
y = [[0.0]*3, [0.0]*3, [0.0]*3, [0.0]*3]
```

Where

```
print y[0] is y[1]     # Output = False
y[1][1] = 5.0
print y      # Output = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
             #           [0.0, 5.0, 0.0], 
             #           [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
             #           [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

Another approach would be to use list comprehension

```
z = [[0.0]*3 for x in range(4)]
```

but, this still seems a little ugly.

Is there a way to make the array 'y' or 'z' where all the references are unique in an elegant format such as in 'x' using multiply on a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in the official Python Programming FAQ, as [How do I create a multidimensional list?](http://docs.python.org/3.3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-multidimensional-list).

The FAQ suggests three possibilities:

1. Create a list of the desired length, then replace each element in a loop.
2. Use a list comprehension.
3. Use something like a numpy.array instead of a multidimensional list in the first place.

I think most Python developers would suggest these in the exact opposite order as they're listed in the FAQ… but nobody would complain about any of them. So:

```
a = np.zeros((3, 4))

a = [[0.0]*3 for _ in range(4)]

a = [None] * 4
for i, _ in enumerate(a):
    a[i] = [0.0]*3
```

---

If you find yourself doing this a lot (and not using numpy), you can always wrap it in a function. In fact, this is generally the best way to deal with *anything* that looks ugly even when you're doing it as pythonically as possible. So:

```
def make_matrix(r, c):
    return [[0.0]*c for _ in range(r)]
```

And then it's about as clear as can be:

```
a = make_matrix(3, 4)
```

---

`itertools` has a function called [`repeat`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat), which is equivalent to the iterator version of `*`. The docs show some equivalent pure Python code, so it's pretty easy to adapt it to (shallow or deep) copy the object for each rep:

```
def repeat(obj, times):
    for _ in range(times):
        yield copy.copy(obj)

list(repeat([0.0]*3, 4))
```

I don't think this is more readable—especially if you want to use it at multiple levels:

```
list(repeat(list(repeat(0.0, 3)), 4))
```

… even if you wrap that in a function that listifies for you:

```
def srepeat(object, times):
    return list(repeat(object, times))
srepeat(srepeat(0.0, 3), 4)
```

… and if you wrap it in a function that handles multiple dimensions, you've just re-created `make_matrix`.

Comment: `itertools.repeat` doesn't work like that. It'll do the same thing as the sequence multiplication code, except with an iterator instead of an outer list.

Comment: @user2357112: You're right; you actually need a function that repeats copies… let me edit the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

List comprehensions are the usual answer. Not as clean as sequence multiplication, but the best that's available:

```
[[0.0]*3 for _ in xrange(4)]
```

Note that for a lot of applications where you want a grid of values, you're doing something that [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) ndarrays could do faster and cleaner.